# Sherman-Morrison Formula with Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Hello I need some advice, does this proof work when $u$ and $v$ are $n \times k$ matrices? I think yes because after outer product of $u$ and $v^{T}$ we will get $(n \times n)$ dimension but I don't know how to show that it can be right.

Assume $A^{-1}$ is known. Prove Sherman-Morrison formula using the following linear system.
$$   \begin{pmatrix}
A & u\\
v^T & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2 
\end{pmatrix} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
b\\
0
\end{pmatrix} $$

So we know that $AX = B$, Now let's try to give the equation form $LUX = B$ where:

$$   U =  \begin{pmatrix}
A & u\\
0 & -1 - v^{T}A^{-1}u 
\end{pmatrix}  \text{ and } L  =  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
v^TA^{-1} & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now if we assume that $UX = Y$ we will get $LY = B \Rightarrow Y = L^{-1}B$

$$  L^{-1} =  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
-v^TA^{-1} & 1 
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$ \Downarrow  $$
$$ Y = L^{-1}B =  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
-v^TA^{-1} & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \cdotp  \begin{pmatrix}
b\\
0
\end{pmatrix}   =  \begin{pmatrix}
b\\
-v^{T}A^{-1}b
\end{pmatrix} $$

Now let's solve $UX = Y$

$$   \begin{pmatrix}
A & u\\
0 & -1 - v^{T}A^{-1}u 
\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2 
\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
b\\
-v^{T}A^{-1}b 
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$ \Downarrow  $$

$$  \begin{pmatrix}
I & A^{-1}u\\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
A^{-1}b\\
\frac{1}{1+v^{T}A^{-1}u} v^{T}A^{-1}b 
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$  \Downarrow $$

$$  x_1 + A^{-1}u x_2 = A^{-1}b $$
$$ x_2 = \frac{v^{T}A^{-1}b}{1+v^{T}A^{-1}u} $$
$$  \Downarrow $$
$$  x_1 = b \left( A^{-1} - \frac{A^{-1}uv^{T}A^{-1}}{1 + v^{T}A^{-1}u}\right)  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your proof does not work as is.
Firstly, the $1$ in the bottom righ should really be a matrix (maybe the identity matrix ?).

The main problem though is that $v^TA^{-1}u$ is not a scalar, it is a matrix and you thus cannot divide so carelessly.

I think what you are looking for is the so-called Woodbbury matrix identity. Wikiedia has a great proof of it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity