# Define $u$ and $v$ (Sherman-Morrison formula)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

can someone give me a hint or explain the question because I did not get what they want.

Thanks in advance.

Define $u$ , $v \in R^{n}$ from $A, B \in R^{n \times n}$ assuming $B = A + uv^{T}$. Describe algorithm.

Comment: You will need to add more details here. For example, seeing the word "algorithm" and the tag, it seems like this is a question in numerical linear-algebra. So what algorithm might be talked about? If you don't know, then next : Do you have a source for this question? If it's in a book, in a certain section, we may be in a position to guess. If it appeared in an online class, the class material would be useful. The problem is that we shouldn't have to answer a question that's unclear : try to provide as much as you can, so we can get rid of the lack of clarity first.

Comment: So it is my homework  problem. The the main problems was on Sherman-Morrisons formula.  First and Second problems you can see here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4314973/847114

Comment: It appears that they want you, given matrices $A,B$, to find column vectors $u, v$ such that $uv^T = B - A$. Obviously, this can only be done when $A, B$ meet stringent conditions, since $uv^T$ is always a degenerate matrix.